# Excel IMABS function returning false value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with complex numbers. 
So in cell(1,1) there is e.g.: **40318,5705419227+153347,941302982i**

If I want to get the absolute value of the number I can insert manually `= IMABS(A1)`, which is giving me the right result: **158559,6993**

But if I want to calculate the statement using vba:

```
string1 = WorksheetFunction.ImAbs(Cells(1, 1).value)
```

it gives me: 431363308773779

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Cells(I1, 1) looks like I1 is a variable?

Comment: Sorry, that´s an error. It must call: Cells(1,1) it is not a variable. I think maybe the funktion uses different data types?

Comment: Thx pnuts! Worked now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, in VBA, that function requires the US decimal symbol.  And your value is using the comma.  The following seems to work:

```
WorksheetFunction.ImAbs (Replace(Cells(1, 1), ",", "."))
```

**EDIT:** This was also suggested by @pnuts in his comment above.

Comment: Thx!!! That worked! pnuts made the same suggestion, but it didn´t work, cause i forgot to disable the automatic type conversion when writing into a cell...

Comment: Oops.  I should have rechecked. @pnuts must have posted while I was checking my solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your value of `40318,5705419227+153347,941302982i` is located in Cell "A1", the correct reference to it would be:

```
String1 = WorksheetFunction.ImAbs(Cells(1, 1).Value2)
```